# SSH to a server, execute update command that continues even after logging off the ssh session

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, tmux, nohup

Okay I saw a lot of questions like this, but almost all have either theoretical answers which do clear the concept but I am still not able to put it up in code.

What I want to achieve using a bash script is, using a loop,

1. `ssh` to servers mentioned in a file ( this is done )
2. execute update and upgrade command on each of them.
3. exit asa the command is issued but the commands should keep running on the server.

Currently, with a normal script to do so, I can `ssh` and update all machines but serially...that is only one machine at a time as `ssh` exits only after the completion of update and upgrade.( with op directed to `/dev/null` to avoid unnecessary op on screen)

I see options like nohup, `screen`/tmux to do so...but I don't get how to use any of these to achieve the above!

How can I implemented this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prepare `update.sh` script which will be run on machines.
Run it inside `screen` with `ssh`:

```
ssh user@host "screen -a -d -m -l -U /usr/local/sbin/update.sh"
```

Profit. It will run update script in dettached screen session, which will end as soon as the update.sh end.

Comment: okay so i just add this in the while loop of shell script?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can also fork `ssh` into background i.e. `ssh user@host "[...]" &` to make the update more parallel on all machines.

Comment: okay...and i could just keep the script in /root and do ./update.sh right?

Comment: You do not need `root` to run this script, but yes you can do it like so. Perhaps you would even run it from `cron`.

Comment: yeah, to avoid password requirements of sudo ive rather made ssh to root :P the environment is not any kind of production environment so its okay :D

Comment: Done! Thankyou so much! Btw, i heard screen isnt maintained anymore and thus tmux is suggested... any suggestion on using tmux?

Comment: man nohup, man bash (output redirection). Though you are better off with a cron job. The script provided by other respondents will do the job.